# get a random number when merging 2 array

Tags: c

I want to merge 2 arrays into 1.  For example:

- A1= 1,1
- A2= 2,2
- then A3 = 1,2,1,2

For example:

- A1= 1
- A2= 2,2,2,2
- then A3 = 1,2,2,2,2

For example:

- A1= 1,1,1,1
- A2= 2,2
- then A3 = 1,2,1,2,1,1

In last example, when I ran my code, I got 1,2,1,2,1,20.

In the second last, I got 1,2,32767,2,2.

So I guess I have a wrong code.  Right after the I finished taking the element of the shorter array and fill up all the rest of the A3 with whoever is longer. But I couldn't figure out why — can you help me?

code:

```
int *p3=arr3;   //arr3 is A3 for example, arr1 = A1..etc, all sizes are defined
int index;
int index1=0;
int index2=0;

for(index = 0; index< sizeofArr3 ; index++)
{
    if(index%2==0)
    {
        if(index1<=sizeofArr1)
            *(p3++) = arr1[index1++];
        else
            *(p3++) = arr2[index2++];
    }
    else 
    {
        if(index2<=sizeofArr2)
            *(p3++) = arr2[index2++];
        else
            *(p3++) = arr1[index1++];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's this line:

```
if (index1 <= sizeofArr1)
```

and the equivalent one for `index2` and `sizeofArr2`. You should be using `<` rather than `<=`.

The reason has to do with C's zero-based arrays. For an array of size `N`, the element indexes are `0` through  `N-1` inclusive. Because you're allowing it to access element `N` (the `N+1`th element), you're actually invoking undefined behaviour.

Theoretically, the implementation can do anything in that case, up to and including destruction of the universe. I guess you're lucky that it just decided to give you results that were slightly awry :-)

Answer (score 2):

Should <= sizeOfArr1 and 2 actually be < sizeOfArr1 and 2? How are you calculating your sizes?

Answer (score 1):

The tests in the loops should be:

```
if (index1 < sizeofArr1)
```

with `<` rather than `<=`, assuming that the `sizeofArr1` is a count of the number of elements in the array, rather than the maximum valid index in the array.  When the arrays are the same length, this discrepancy doesn't matter (so the first sequence was OK), but when the arrays are different lengths, it does matter.